# Other ways of saying "letting me know" or "telling me about"

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

I want to say “my advisor has been very helpful, from helping me decide which classes to take to letting me know/telling me about the resources available to me”.

I think saying “letting me know” or “telling me about” is too clunky.

Are there any other ways of saying this?

Comment: @MετάEd, perhaps you could cease and desist from edits that only change quote marks, unless you make a compelling case for such edits via [meta].  (Note, both [Feature request: Rounded quotes in WMD toolbar](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2923) and [Should we automatically convert straight ' and " quotes into nicer “…” and ‘…’ quotes?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/535) implicitly assume quotes should be converted; I don't know of a meta question that directly asks "Should they be converted?" vs "Should they be automatically converted?".

Comment: Whenever I would like to express my sincere gratitude, I turn to the part 'Words of Thanks' of Douglas R. Hofstadter's 'Gödel, Escher, Bach'. It is very inspiring.

Answer (score 4):

There are *always* other ways to say something. Maybe you could say:

> My advisor has been helpful, from helping me decide on courses to take to *informing me* about available resources.

Answer (score 0):

*Describing* perhaps, and its [synonyms](http://thesaurus.com/browse/describe) or maybe *listing* and its synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) My advisor has been very helpful, from helping me decide which classes
>   to take to ***guiding me*** toward the resources available to
>   me

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/guide) defines the *verb* ***guide*** as

> *transitive verb* **2** a :  to direct, supervise, or influence usually to  a particular end
>   e.g. *Her example helped to guide me toward a career in medicine.*
>
> Usage notes: *guide* implies intimate knowledge of the way and of all its difficulties and dangers

N.B. You don't normally *guide* a person *about* something, in the OP's sentence the following prepositions: *to*, *toward*, or *through* would be more appropriate.

Alternatively, consider the verb ***counsel*** which means to give advice, as in:

> *Careers officers should [counsel](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/counsel) young people in making their career decisions*
>
> 2) My advisor has been very helpful, from helping me decide which classes to take to ***counselling*** me about the resources available.

Answer (score -3):

Your advisor? Just use advised.

Comment: *Advised* would be a poor choice stylistically in the example sentence (with *adviser* already mentioned).

Comment: @AndrewLeach   stylistically poor perhaps, but it fits. And who says *advisor* cannot be changed to *mentor* / *tutor* / *counsellor* etc.